# Missing "./saga" specifier in "redux" package

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm learning redux-saga and tried to setup in my React application but I was stuck with this error:

> Missing "./saga" specifier in "redux" package

product.saga.js

```js
import { takeLatest, all, call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { getAllProducts } from "./product.utils";

export function* fetchProductsAsync() {
    try {
        const apiResponse = yield call(getAllProducts)
        yield put(fetchProductsSuccess(apiResponse))
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(fetchProductsFailed(error))
    }
}

export function* onFetchProducts() {
    yield takeLatest(
        ProductActionTypes.GET_ALL,
        fetchProductsAsync
    )
}

export function* productsSaga() {
    yield all([
        call(onFetchProducts)
    ])
}
```

root-saga.js

```js
import { all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

import { productsSaga } from './products/product.saga'

export function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        call(productsSaga)
    ])
}
```

store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { logger } from 'redux-logger'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux/saga'
import { rootSaga } from './root-saga'
import rootReducer from './root-reducer'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const middlewares = [logger, sagaMiddleware]

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares))

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export const persistor = persistStore(store)

export default { store, persistor }
```

Tried to re-run `npm install` on redux & redux-saga but still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import from `'redux/saga'`, which does definitely not exist. (Saga is not included in the `redux` package and generally we wouldn't recommend it for most usages nowadays.)

Did you maybe want to import from `'redux-saga'`?

Also, please note that `createStore, applyMiddleware` are very outdated (pre-2019) ways of setting up a Redux store that end up in Redux code that's 3-4 times as much code as modern Redux - you might generally be following a very outdated tutorial. I'd recommend the official Redux tutorial to learn Redux: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that haha yeah you're right it should be 'redux-saga' and thanks for the recommendation!